# SharePoint online downloadable link

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, storage-file-share

we need to share the file from SharePoint online to customer as a downloadable link. the current SharePoint 'Copy link' option is making the opening of the file directly in the browser. is there any alternative way to make the SharePoint online file as downloadable by clicking on link.

whenever customer click the SharePoint online direct file link it should get downloaded and not open in a browser.

I have already tried by adding 'download.aspx' to end of the below SharePoint link but unable to access.

*[https://domain.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/[site-name]/[token]?dowload.aspx](https://domain.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/%5Bsite-name%5D/%5Btoken%5D?dowload.aspx)*

Please suggest any alternative way to SharePoint online file link as downloadable.

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for programming questions and questions about sharing a SharePoint link is off topic here. Take a look at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

@Ramesh Subramanyamvari,

You can use below link to download file:

Source sharing link:

```
https://abc.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/s01/EYW-JSP1TBtGkk3u9LGfqvIBp1CaePZY30X9FCZPPxoM0g?e=Og98U2
```

Download link:

```
https://abc.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/s01/EYW-JSP1TBtGkk3u9LGfqvIBp1CaePZY30X9FCZPPxoM0g?download=1
```

Or

```
https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/_layouts/15/download.aspx?share=EYW-JSP1TBtGkk3u9LGfqvIBp1CaePZY30X9FCZPPxoM0g
```

BR

Comment: Hi BR! thanks for your replay! I have tried all the above options that you suggested but no difference, the file is still opening but not downloading.

Comment: can you share one link? it works fine in my SPO library.